# Multiple EMF sources in a parallel circuit, semantics

Tags: batteries, parallel, generator, series

Simple question, really. Need some clarity on parallel vs. series-opposing circuits.

[image: parallel circuit with 2 EMF sources and 3 loads]

V1 is an automotive gen/alt, assume 80A max output. BAT1 is a lead-acid battery. V1 is charging the battery and powering R1 and R2. Is it correct to call V1/BAT1 a series-opposing circuit here? Or simply a parallel circuit with KCL junctions? With SW1 closed, circuit draw will be over 100A and BAT1 will be discharging, obviously in parallel with V1 and the loads.

I see the terms "series-opposing" and "series-aiding" used when describing more than one voltage source in **series**. Can 2 parallel-connected voltage sources ever be described as **series**?

Comment: 'obviously' is not 'obviously'. You are making some assumptions - realistic ones in the context of car components - but those are not reflected on the schematic. As per the schematic alone, when SW1 is closed, V1 continues to supply all of the current required by the resistors and BAT1 continues to charge. You have not shown the current limit or output impedance of V1 which causes it to fail, the voltage to drop, and BAT1 to start supplying current.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I did specify that V1 would have 80A max output. The question has come up in an automotive forum "can the gen/alt and the battery be parallel sometimes and series-opposing other times"? Not forgetting all the other loads.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to call V1/BAT1 a series-opposing circuit here?

V1 and BAT1 are in parallel. Each terminal of one component is connected to the corresponding terminal of the other component.

> Or simply a parallel circuit with KCL junctions?

I'm not sure what you mean by "KCL junctions". KCL applies to all lumped element circuits. What is common in a parallel arrangement of components is that they have identical voltages across them. Perhaps you meant to say KVL? In any event, if you connect a 14V generator across a 13.5 volt battery, one or the other component (or both) will have to adjust their voltage so that the voltage across each is the same. If the generator is strong, the voltage across the battery will rise to 14V and the battery will begin charging.

> With SW1 closed, circuit draw will be over 100A and BAT1 will be discharging, obviously in parallel with V1 and the loads.

The voltage across the battery and the generator will be equal. If that voltage is above the open circuit voltage of the battery, then the battery will charge. If that voltage is below the open circuit voltage of the battery then the battery will discharge.

> Can 2 parallel-connected voltage sources ever be described as series?

Yes. If they are the only elements in the circuit, then they are both "in series" and "in parallel". The voltage across each will be the same, and also the current through each will be the same.

Comment: Thanks Math. The question arose in an online automotive forum. The series group admits the circuit is parallel, but the battery is "series-opposing" during charging, parallel during discharge. They also claim "2 voltages". The parallel group states the circuit is simply parallel, same voltage across the battery and all loads, and current is divided between all loads. Agreed, if V1 and BAT1 were the only elements in the circuit, they could be called series-opposing or parallel. But there are multiple paths for V1's current, making it a parallel circuit.